# How to associate event with all editors opened in a page in Eclipse

Tags: events, eclipse-plugin, abstract-syntax-tree

Using the below code I am able to capture all the key events in currently active editor (First.java) in eclipse

```java
IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
IEditorPart editor = page.getActiveEditor();
((StyledText)editor.getAdapter(org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.class)).addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
        //code here 
   });
```

But as soon as I open (Activate) another editor (Second.java), key event are not captured.

[image]

How can I capture key events on all the editors I open in workbenchPage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `IPartListener` to listen for changes to the active part so that you can add and remove your listener as the part changes:

```java
IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();

page.addPartListener(listener);
```

The listener is told about parts being opened, closed, activated and deactivated. The parts may be Views or Editors.

Note: Not all editors use `StyledText` so you need to check the type of the object returned by `getAdapter`.